Placing $n$ particles in $m$ states in Statistical Thermodynamics
I am doing Statistical Mechanics and want to find the number of possible microstates of $n$ particles placed into $m$ directional states of vibration. The particles are indistinguishable, but the vibrational states are not.
Have looked at some combinatorics text but I do not follow their approach very well because they use the multinomial coefficients.
I started with an example of five indistinguishable particles that I place into 6 vibrational states.  I cannot see that the formula is for combinations of value $m^n$.  How can I start thinking about this ?  Is there any good website that would help me on this?

For the Community to be able to properly answer your question, there is a minimum quality standard that applies to all new questions. Read more on how to ask a good question.
To say the least, add your own thoughts and considerations on the problem so that contributors can navigate you.

In combinatorics we have this basic rule that we call the product rule. What it says is this: if you can do the first step of some thing in $m$ ways and second step in $n$ ways, then you can do the whole thing in $mn$ ways. Here we will use the same idea. Each of the particles can be in $m$ different states. So the entire system can be in $m\cdot m\cdots m$ (multiply $n$ times) many states, which is $m^n$.
But that is only the case when the steps are independent, that is if they are distinct.
But now you have indistinguishable particles. So we only care about how many of each state is there. Say we have $n_1$ many particles in state $1$, $n_2$ in state $2$, $\dots$, $n_m$ many in state $m$. Also, you have
$$n_1+n_2+\dots+n_m=n$$
So, the number of states become the same as the number of ways of partitioning $n$ like this, which is $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$ by stars and bars method (see this for reference). That should be your answer.
As to how the stars and bars work is this: So we basically want to put n things in m boxes (Some boxes might even be empty). Think of your things as stars ••••••••.
You have $n$ many of them. Now think of $(m-1)$ many bars along with the stars, in some arrangement like this:
•|••|||••|•••••|
Now we will say that the number of things before the first bar is the number of things you put in first box, the number of things between the first and second bar is what you put in the second box and so on. Like this we get the number of things in each box. Note that some of the bars are consecutive so the boxes are empty. So the problem reduces to ways in which you can arrange this bars and stars. Now notice that there are $m-1$ many bars and $n$ many stars. So total ways of putting them together is $\dfrac{(n+m-1)!}{(m-1)!n!}$
Hope this helps.

But is the $m^n$ the correct answer regarding placing $n$ indistinguishable particles into $m$ states ?

No it is not. It is correct only if the particles are distinct. Sorry I read the question as distinguishable the first time. I edited it. I hope it is clear now.

My difficulty is about convincing myself it is $\frac{(n+m-1)!}{(m-1)! n!}$

Did you check the link? It is explained there. Or do you want me to edit the answer to explain it?

If you just want to be convinced you can try with small cases also. Let me know what you want I'll edit the answer accordingly to help.

It would help me to understand the production of the formula.  Although I have perused the link, I found it very mathematical, whereas I would like to approach it as a physical problem for me to figure it out.

Haw can I focus on the concept of stars and bars?  All the mathematical argumentation with "the number of multisets of cardinality $k − 1$ taken from a set of size $n + 1$" dulls my mind something awful.

I have edited the answer. Check if you understand now.

I understand the argumentation well enough now.  Felicitations.

For indistinguishable particles, the idea is that we cannot say which particle is in which state, because that would be to distinguish them from eachother, we can only say how many particles are in a given state.
Let $n_i$ be the number of particles in state $i\in \{1,...,m\}$. Since there are $n$ particles,
$$\sum_{i=1}^m n_i=n.$$
Thus, another way to phrase this question is, `How many partitions of $n$ into $m$ parts are there?' As noted here, the answer is
$$\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}.$$

Strictly speaking, in physics, indistinguishable particles which can be in the same state as eachother are known as Bosons. If you were asking about Fermions, those which cannot be in the same state, then the answer would of course be
$$\binom{m}{n}$$
with the convention that $\binom{m}{n}=0$ for $m>n$.

Correct, we can only say how many particles are in a given state.

I am talking about bosons in my case.
